# Getting information friends on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I started studying the Facebook Graph API. I would like to take a list of friends, and output personal information (general information, employment and education, and etc). How can i do this?

Friends list getting so:
 AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

```
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "me/taggable_friends?name,id",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    //parse JSON

                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

I tried use "me/friends/{Getting_higher_id}", but it's not work.
{Getting_higher_id} looks like -> AaRD2Kuv4vBnWfSaUZ2BRT2T3x4Su8MpFii4ZTB_20JwDBgQCMxZDhhLu2Cdylb-PaxZqt2mUXdAmbepjoTrKQRor2Dc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only, you are not allowed to use it for anything else. If you just want to get information, you must use `/me/friends`, and you can only get friends who authorized your App too. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

It is not possible at all to get data from friends who did not authorize your App. You can only get a limited tagging or invite token with the name of the friend for tagging or inviting friends to a game.